# Как сделать такой строчно-блочный список с помощью css?

Tags: html, css

Как можно сделать такой строчно-блочный список, как на фото:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `display: inline-block;`

Comment: @Elena, пробовал, не получается, текст списка заходят друг под друга и маркеры пропадают

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что вопрос-картинка бесполезен для базы знаний.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это можно осуществить с помощью [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

```css
body {font-family: arial;}
ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: 500px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
ul > li {
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
}
ul > li > .header {
  display: flex;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: #073361;
}
ul > li > .header:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width:12px;
  height: 12px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background-color: #41b7c3;
}
ul > li > .text {
  display:block;
  padding-left: 34px;
  color: #22578f;
}
/* #41b7c3 */
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><div class="header">Header</div><div class="text">Text</div></li>
  <li><div class="header">Header</div><div class="text">Text</div></li>
  <li><div class="header">Header</div><div class="text">Text</div></li>
  <li><div class="header">Header</div><div class="text">Text</div></li>
  <li><div class="header">Header</div><div class="text">Text</div></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: огромное спасибо

Answer (score -2):

```css
ul {
  list-style: square;
  font-size: 20px;
}

li {
  color: #42B6C3;
}

.hd {
  color: #3A5775;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.cn {
  color: #7B90AB
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td>
  

    <ul>
    <li><span class="hd">head</span></li>
      <span class="cn">text text text text text</span>
    </ul>
  
    <ul>
      <li><span class="hd">head</span></li>
      <span class="cn">text text text text text</span>
    </ul> 
    
    <ul>
      <li><span class="hd">head</span></li>
      <span class="cn">text text text text text</span>
    <ul>  

  
</td><td>
  
  <ul>
    <li><span class="hd">head</span></li>
      <span class="cn">text text text text text</span>
    </ul>
  
    <ul>
      <li><span class="hd">head</span></li>
      <span class="cn">text text text text text</span>
    </ul> 
    
    <ul>
      <li><span class="hd">head</span></li>
      <span class="cn">text text text text text</span>
    <ul>
  
</td></tr>
</table>
```

Поскольку народ испугался таблиц из ужасных баек фронэндеров я заменил её на div. Хотя если подумать таблицы это основополагающий элемент в электронных документах.

```css
ul {
  list-style: square;
  font-size: 20px;
}

li {
  color: #42B6C3;
}

.hd {
  color: #3A5775;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.cn {
  color: #7B90AB
}

.ux {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="ux">
  

    <ul>
    <li><span class="hd">head</span></li>
      <span class="cn">text text text text text</span>
    </ul>
  
    <ul>
      <li><span class="hd">head</span></li>
      <span class="cn">text text text text text</span>
    </ul> 
    
    <ul>
      <li><span class="hd">head</span></li>
      <span class="cn">text text text text text</span>
    </ul>  

  
</div>
<div class="ux">
  
  <ul>
    <li><span class="hd">head</span></li>
      <span class="cn">text text text text text</span>
    </ul>
  
    <ul>
      <li><span class="hd">head</span></li>
      <span class="cn">text text text text text</span>
    </ul> 
    
    <ul>
      <li><span class="hd">head</span></li>
      <span class="cn">text text text text text</span>
    </ul>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Конечно пример рабочий, но он какой-то странный )

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму а флексбох это экспериментальная технология. мне кажется два дива в элемент списка сувать не правильно. ну css огромный ко всему )

Comment: @perfect, почему не правильно? Это займёт меньше места в `CSS`

Comment: flexbox во всех современных браузерах поддерживается нормально, самый хороший на текущий момент ответ дала @Elena в комментариях. А Вы мешаете структуру с внешним видом. Ну серьезно, этот ответ был морально устаревшим лет пять назад. Работать то работает, но верстай вы так в нормальном проекте - никто с вами разговаривать не будет.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, ответ то хороший, но `inline-block` иногда выкаблучивается, когда меняешь размеры

Comment: @Yuri, у флексбоксов тоже багов хватает (и их больше). Ну ладно, на крайняк можно флоаты. Но таблицы... Btw мне неизвестно про баги с display:inline-block при ресайзе, которые бы не фиксились легко

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму а вы думаете я таких комментариев не ожидал )). если думать логически li это строчный элемент, а div блочный. ну а по правилам блочный в строчный нельзя заворачивать, а наоборот можно )

Comment: @perfect, спасибо, действительно не плохой вариант с div,работает